# Log in Azure AD with a Symfony3 API

Tags: php, api, symfony, azure, office365

I'm currently trying to develop a **Symfony3** API. This API needs to find if the user already exist in the **AD** of the company.

**Problem**:

I can't use any user interface, and all I found about getting log with **Azure AD** redirects me to a web page which asks graphically for username and password.

I need a way to proceed this step with no graphical intervention.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to check your user in the company AD tenant in your PHP backend service without user login. If I have any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.

You can try to leverage [`Microsoft Graph`](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us) in your application, and implement within OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow to [Call Microsoft Graph in a service or daemon app](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only).

You can then get access token to build REST requests against to Microsoft Graph, and use [Get a user](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get) to check whether the user is in your AD tenant.